# Boost size of largest connected component

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I know how to calculate the total number of connected components in Boost, but is there an efficient way to compute the size of the largest connected component using the boost's graph library.

Comment: Did you have something to show that your question is about? It's not /that/ informative that _you_ know how to do something related.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient way is to replace the [component map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:%7E:text=The%20ComponentMap%20type%20must%20be%20a%20model%20of%20Writable%20Property%20Map.) with a custom type.

I created a small [WritePropertyMap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/property_map/doc/WritablePropertyMap.html) to do that:

```
template <typename V>
struct Mapper {
    using Id          = int; // component id
    using Cardinality = int;

    using Map   = boost::container::flat_map<Id, Cardinality>;
    using Value = Map::value_type;
    Map& storage;

    friend void put(Mapper& m, V const& /*v*/, Id id) { m.storage[id] += 1; }

    Value largest() const {
        return not storage.empty()
            ? *max_element(begin(storage), end(storage),
                   [](Value const& a, Value const& b) {
                       return a.second < b.second;
                   })
            : Value{};
    }
};
```

We need to tell Boost about our property map:

```
template <typename V> struct boost::property_traits<Mapper<V>> {
    using category   = boost::writable_property_map_tag;
    using key_type   = V;
    using value_type = int;
};
```

> ### Note
>
> *The separation between storage and property map is because property maps are passed by value - and should be cheap to copy.*

Now we can use it, adapting the [library example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/example/connected_components.cpp) slightly:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/732f3df3e93ab212)**

```
Mapper<V>::Map result;
Mapper<V> mapper{result};
int num = connected_components(g, mapper);

auto [id, cardinality] = mapper.largest();
std::cout << "Largest component #" << id << " (out of " << num
          << " components) has " << cardinality << " vertices\n";
```

Prints

```
Largest component #0 (out of 3 components) has 3 vertices
```

This matches the expected output.

### BONUS

If you have an expected number of components, you may be able to optimize storage by using small_vector/static_vector, e.g.

```
using Value = std::pair<Id, Cardinality>;
using Map = boost::container::flat_map<
    Id, Cardinality, std::less<>,
    boost::container::small_vector<Value, 10>>;
```

This way, unless you have more than 10 components, you will never see a dynamic allocation for the mapper storage.

Comment: I'm quite curious whether you ever found this answer, whether it worked for you?

Comment: Sorry, for the late response, and thank you very much for the answer. Your method looks right to me. But for some reason, I have used another library than boost.

Comment: That explains. Thanks for the response :)